# Initializing an array of pointers to a defined structure with constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

```
struct Mystruct
{
  int x;
  int y;
  Mystruct(int x, int y);
}
------------------------
class Myclass
{
  Mystruct** p;
  Myclass(int n);
}
------------------------
Myclass::Myclass(int n)
{
  this->p = new Mystruct*[n];
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    this->p[i] = new Mystruct[n];
}
```

This will not work. I know the problem lies somewhere with default constructor not being available, but I do not know how to move forward from here.

Comment: `this->p*` why that '*' ?

Comment: this->p[i] is not an array pointer. try ```this->p[I] = new MyClass();```

Comment: First things first, i'll give the obligatory `std::vector<std::vector<Mystruct>> p (n, std::vector<Mystruct>(n));` would be much safer and avoid manual memory management. Anyway, it's unclear to me what you want all the `Mystruct` to contain in terms of data.

Comment: I repaired it to this->p. @George It is a school project related where we are not allowed to use vectors. In Mystruct I want to have two integers x and y with information about a predescor on a chessboard.

Comment: you want Myclass to be a square of Mystruct ? do `this->p = new Mystruct*[n];`

Comment: Don't forget to write destructor:

Comment: This cannot work for a number of reasons, the syntax being minor to them. `p` is a pointer to pointer to `MyStruct`, so `this->p = new Myclass*[n]` make no sense. And your mandated arguments for the ctor are going to make that array-allocation... interesting, even if you somehow fix that type problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want

```
Myclass::Myclass(int n)
{
  this->p = new Mystruct*[n];
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    this->p[i] = new Mystruct[n];
}
```

because `Mystruct** p;`

You also need to save the dimension, and to add a destructor, very probably the constructor must be public.

As said in a remark to be able to allocate your array of *Mystruct* that one need a constructor without parameter

Comment: ...and a default ctor to `Mystruct`, or that inner array-allocation is doomed.

Comment: Thank you guys, it seems that all the warnings evaporated as I wrote a default constructor. Is it ok to have an empty default constructor in this situation set as ```Mystruct::Mystruct(){}``` ?

Comment: @Milan yes else impossible to do `new Mystruct[n];`